# Changing woocommerce subscription interval from yearly to monthly only for one subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

In woocommerce subscription administrator is not able to edit the **Billing Schedule** Is there anyway that administrator may able to edit the **Billing Schedule** recurring field. It is not editable from wp-admin

How can i change the recurring from monthly to yearly for just subscription of a customer as it is not editable? Transaction has already been took placed.

As shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I want to change Recurring: every month to every year

Please help

Comment: Admins should be able to change any recurring variable. Did you [follow the directions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/add-or-modify-a-subscription/#section-11)?

Comment: Yes I have checked and follow but there is not option to edit for Billing Schedule section. These are read-only.

Comment: But billing details and shipping details are editable

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are your customers able to change this setting through their subscription profile? Since it may be tied to the payment processor, it may only be editable through the front end. If that's the case, you may find [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-administrator-password/) helpful

Comment: There is also the possibility that some editable features were disabled manually through the theme's  ***functions.php** file.  Look for any functions in this file that look anything [like this](https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/8851189#file-wcs-disallow-subscription-actions-php) and comment out temporarily.